# How to get a System.Reflection.Metadata.MethodDefintion from System.Reflection.MethodBase.MetadataToken?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection, system.reflection.metadata

I have created a `System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader` for an .NET assembly:

```cs
var asm = new PEReader(peFile);
var asmReader = asm.GetMetadataReader();
```

I can loop over all `MethodDefinitions`, but how do I find a specific `MethodDefinition`, for a given instance of `System.Reflection.MethodBase`?

Can I use `MethodBase.MetadataToken` to lookup the correct MethodDefinition?

I also want to lookup the corresponding `MethodDebugInformation` from the Portable PDB; but that should be easy after finding the `MethodDefinition`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the solution is simple enough, `System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335` contains a `MetadataTokens` class with methods to create handles, which can then be used to lookup the MethodDefinition:

```cs
var handle = (MethodDefinitionHandle)MetadataTokens.Handle(metadataToken);
var md = asmReader.GetMethodDefinition(handle);
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer to mark this question as solved